# R - Plotly: Get the id of a clicked graph

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Plotly has the function event_data which will respond to clicks on points of a plot. However, you have to specify a "source" for event_data which identifies the plot you want to watch.

Is there a way to respond to clicks on any plot and get the source id of the given click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a source list, but you have to keep track of the changes yourself as only a new click on a given plot overwrites a previous click event:

```
shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot1"),
                      plotlyOutput("plot2")), 
         server=
function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly(plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, source="plot1"))
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly(plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, source="plot2"))

  states <- reactiveValues(source = c("plot1", "plot2"), value = c(0,0), changed = c(FALSE,FALSE))

  observe({
    for(src in states$source){
      if( !is.null(event_data("plotly_click", source = src) ) ){
        value <- event_data("plotly_click", source = src)[[2]]
        if(states$value[states$source==src]!=value ){
          states$value[states$source==src] <- value
          states$changed[states$source==src] <- TRUE
        }
      }
    }
    if(sum(states$changed)>0)
      print(paste(states$source[states$changed], 'has changed'))
    states$changed <- c(FALSE,FALSE)
  })
})
```